# Long set description

Tags: line-breaking, amsmath

I want to define the following set whose description is too long. How do I break it into two?

```
$L_4 =\lbrace{ w \mid w \text{ every } 1 \text{ in } w \text{ is either preceded or followed (not necessarily immediately) } \\ \text{by two (need not be consecutive) }  0's\rbrace} $
```

Comment: not relevant to the formatting, but it's "preceding", not "preceeding".

Comment: Note that you shouldn't have `{` after `\lbrace` nor `}` after `\rbrace`.

Comment: Consider adding a *minimal working example* (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to make it easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a displayed equation, a `tabular` can be used and the brackets and line increased:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  L_4 =\left\lbrace w \;\middle|\;
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    every 1 in $w$ is either preceded or followed (not necessarily\\
    immediately) by two (need not be consecutive) 0's
   \end{tabular}
  \right\rbrace
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Alternative is a `\parbox`, see Barbara's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247044/long-set-description/247049#comment587531_247049). The following example uses environment `varwidth`, a modified `minipage`, which automatically reduces the width to the needed amount.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
  L_4 =\left\lbrace w \;\middle|\;
  \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
    every 1 in $w$ is either preceded or followed (not necessarily\\
    immediately) by two (need not be consecutive) 0's
   \end{varwidth}
  \right\rbrace
\\
  L_4 =\left\lbrace w \;\middle|\;
  \begin{varwidth}{.5\linewidth}
    every 1 in $w$ is either preceded or followed (not necessarily
    immediately) by two (need not be consecutive) 0's
   \end{varwidth}
  \right\rbrace
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Variant with `enumerate`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
  $\displaystyle % simulate displayed equation
  L_4 =\left\lbrace w \;\middle|\;
  \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
    every 1 in $w$ is either preceded or followed (not necessarily\\
    immediately) by two (need not be consecutive) 0's
   \end{varwidth}
  \right\rbrace$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with enumerate]

Comment: a `parbox` should also work.  (see also comment above on "preceding",)

Comment: @Heiko Oberdiek This is perfect. This set comes within a \begin{enumerate} ... \end{enumerate} as an \item. Can i make the number of the set in the enumeration appear exactly in the same line as L_4?

Comment: @barbarabeeton I have added a variant with environment `varwidth` and fixed the typo.

Comment: @rookie Variant with `enumerate` added.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use math mode for the whole thing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

This is the set we all love
$L_4 =\lbrace w \mid{}$every $1$~in~$w$ is either
preceded or followed (not necessarily immediately)
by two (need not be consecutive)~$0$'s$\rbrace$
and some other text follows.

\end{document}
```

(I removed a `w` just after `\mid` that seemed out of place).

[image]

However, your readers will have a hard time in finding the closing brace. Long set descriptions should be set in words:

```
We denote by $L_4$ the set of words~$w$ such that 
every $1$~in~$w$ is either preceded or followed 
(not necessarily immediately) by two~$0$'s (which
need not be consecutive).
```